# How can I increase by one each value contained in the values list in Python

Tags: python, list

```
values = [16, 1, 7, 2, 19, 12, 5, 20, 2, 10, 10, 14, 17, 14, 1, 16, 19, 7, 9, 19]
```

If I want to increase by one each value contained in the values list, why can't I do like this:

this is my answer, but it's wrong

```
for i in values:
    i += 1
print(values)
```

why do I only have to do in this way

```
for i in range(len(values)): 
    values[i] += 1
print(values)
```

Comment: `values = [x+1 for x in values]`

Comment: Print `i` in your first for loop. You are adding 1 to each value in your `values` list, but you aren't assigning those values back into your list

Comment: Because `i += 1`doesn't modify the list. It creates a new `int` object and assigns it to the variable `i`

Comment: That's a horrible duplicate. `+=` is an assignment statement. In your first example `i += 1` only reassigned to the temporary variable `i`. In your second example, `value[i] += 1` reassigned the value at the ith index.